# Livecode not recognizing variable value

Tags: livecode

I’ve built an application in Livecode where there are nine buttons on a card.  Eight of the buttons play short music samples and have a variable that holds the number of times the button was pushed. Holding down the mouse button allows the buttons to be dragged around the card as well.  The ninth button starts a script that surveys the variables associated with the eight sample buttons and ensures that all the samples have been listened to at least once.  The script puts the eight variables into one variable and then checks to see if they are empty.  If they are, the script returns an error message prompting them to make sure they have listened to all the samples.  The problem I’m having is that this works for all but one of the buttons – the one associated with variable gVar08.  If this button has not been pressed, gVar08 remains empty and does not trigger the error message.  I can’t figure out why.  The scripts associated with the sample button and the evaluation button are provided below.

```
#Code for music sample button
global gVar08
on mouseDown
   wait 30
   if the mouseClick then
   play audioClip "samples/C1/C1-8ConcertoForViolinStringsAndHarpsichordInGR202IAllegroMolto.wav"
   set the filename of image "icn08" to "icons/if_abstract_symbol-03_1571964a.png"
   add 1 to gVar08
   else
      grab me
      end if
end mouseDown


#Code assigned to 9th button: Check to see if all samples played at least 1x
global gVar01, gVar02, gVar03, gVar04, gVar05, gVar06, gVar07, gVar08, gErr01
local sClct
on mouseUp
   put gVar01, gVar02, gVar03, gVar04, gVar05, gVar06, gVar07, gVar08 into sClct
   repeat for each item local in sClct
      if local = "" then
         answer "Have you listened to all of the samples?  Be sure to play them all."
         add 1 to gErr01
         break
      end if
   end repeat 
end mouseDown
```

Comment: Have you done any bug-hunting? Like printing the value of the faulty variable before and after you set the value. My suggestion is also to use a behavior for the different buttons. Then you only need 1 code to check.

Comment: Yes.  I've used a text box to monitor the value of gVar08 on the main card and have printed values out to a text file.  If I don't press the button associated with gVar08, it's blank in both the text box and text file.  I also tried declaring the value as empty at the open of the card to ensure it wasn't occupied by a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma and “” after gVar08 in the list.  When it is empty, the list ends with 7.  Adding a this should always include the last value even if empty.

Comment: That works!  Thank you!  I had a feeling it was something like this. I was tempted to add an additional empty variable to the list (e.g. gVar09), but this strikes me as not the best practice.  Just curious.  Would you happen to be able to cite a source for your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since `local` is a reserved word, have you tried using a different variable?

Comment: I agree with you on the reserved word issue.  Some of this code was borrowed from an online source and plan to clean it up including dropping 'local' in that script.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your Music Sample button code to work, probably due to the mouseClick function within a mouseDown handler not triggering, so I came up with this option:

```
global gVar08
local sMove

on mouseUp
   if sMove then
      put empty into sMove
      exit to top --Avoids playing the audio and adding 1 to gVar08 on move
   end if
   play audioClip "samples/C1/C1-8ConcertoForViolinStringsAndHarpsichordInGR202IAllegroMolto.wav"
   set the filename of image "icn08" to "icons/if_abstract_symbol-03_1571964a.png"
   add 1 to gVar08
end mouseUp

on mouseStillDown
   if the mouse is down then
      put "true" into sMove
      grab me
   end if
end mouseStillDown
```

Hope this helps.

Paul

Comment: I want to thank you for this.  I'm just getting started with this and more examples are helpful; however, this doesn't answer the question.